# Permutation with atleast n unique characters

Tags: number-theory, permutations

I came across this question on Google APAC 2015. I am slightly weak with permutations.
The problem goes like this:

> There is a password. We know the length of the password and the characters used in the password. The length of the password is n. The number of characters used in the password is m. 
>   Each of these characters appears atleast once in the password.
>   How do we find the total number of possible passwords?

I tried to subtract all the permutations of the passwords which had m-1 unique characters, m-2 unique characters and so on from m^n. But how to find the number of passwords of length n with m-1 unique characters in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this sort of problem, use the **in-and-out principle** aka the [**inclusion-exclusion principle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). The answer to your specific question (the number of surjections from an $n$-element set to an $m$-element set) is
$$\binom m0m^n-\binom m1(m-1)^n+\binom m2(m-2)^n-\binom m3(m-3)^n+\cdots.$$

Note that, in order to answer your question, you **don't** have to determine the number of passwords containing exactly $m-1$ distinct characters. That can **also** be done with (a more general form of) the in-and-out formula, but it's not needed for your problem.

Comment: Ok so I had a look at the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion and if I followed it right, I understand that your equation is finding the union of each of the components. But I didn't understand what each of these components mean? what does C(m,0) * m^n mean? Sorry I am weak in permutations and combinations.

Comment: $\binom m0 = 1$, so the first term is just $m^n$, which is the number of **all** possible words of length $n$ over an alphabet of $m$ letters, **without** the requirement that every letter must occur.